# Связка Web-камеры и Web-страницы Full Resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть страница, на которой находится пользователь. Мне нужно получить изображение с Web-камеры с максимальным разрешением.

Полученное изображение я буду отправлять POST запросом на сервер.

Как (какими технологиями) можно получить фотографию с WEB-камеры?

Есть одно условие - пользователь не должен нажимать дополнительных кнопочек (например на самой камере). Разрешение на использование камеры для браузера есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще это осуществляется в настоящее время с помощью `navigator.getUserMedia()`.

Драфт по getUserMedia здесь:

- [Media Capture and Streams](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html) (англ.)

Подробное описание с хорошим рабочим примером:

- [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) (англ.)
- [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5, русский вариант](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) — перевод на русский